# Build failed, wrong class imported?

Tags: java, android

I am trying to build a very simple Android app, with just instantiating one class, but for some reason it fails and doesn't build, I am probably making some fundamental mistake but am unable to figure out what it is.

```
package algon.app;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import anroid.widget.TextView;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.content.Context;

public class AlgonActivity extends Activity
{
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    TextView t = new TextView(Context context);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    }
}
```

It just doesn't want to instantiate the TextView class, I can't understand why actually.

Thank you for response in advance

Comment: `import anroid.widget.TextView;`

should be 

`import android.widget.TextView;`

misspelled "android". Unless that was a typo in your post

Answer (score 1):

```
TextView t = new TextView(Context context);
```

should be:

```
TextView t = new TextView(this);
```

Comment: Thank you, I just had problems figuring out what the Context class does, it is actually a reference to the Activity method itself.